how can i properly include a path with spaces in cmake on windows powershell and augment it with variable or command to pass to gcc?
the only thing that works is manually putting the entire path with single qoutes '.
like
cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-IC:/Program" "Files" "(x86)/Windows" "Kits/10/Include/x/um' -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S ..

where it is all encased in ' and the spaces are encased in " which is the only way it works but the problem is the x directory changes so i had $((ls 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include')[0].name) in place of x to get the first available version but i cant call commands or variables inside '.
DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-IC:/Program" "Files" "(x86)/Windows" "Kits/10/Include/x/um' is the part I'm talking about
I tried \ before spaces, tried in casing ' before and after the spaces, using " to encase the entire thing somehow escapes the spaces still as well, same with \ before the spaces, only encasing the spaces with " they all break the path resulting in the same errors:
g++.exe: warning: Files: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++.exe: error: Files: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
g++.exe: warning: (x86)/Windows: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++.exe: error: (x86)/Windows: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
g++.exe: warning: Kits/10/Include: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++.exe: error: Kits/10/Include: linker input file not found: No such file or directory

I tried other things like putting the path in a variable before but it breaks also, i tried segmenting the variables into things like $f="'" and $r='"' as part of the final variable or straight in the cmake command but still the same result. Is it really impossible to get the directory dynamically and I have to hard code it here? I tried in a similar thing in a linux bash shell with spaces and variable in the same cmake flag to include something and it had no issues so i am so confused as to why this is happening and cant find a way around it.

In Powershell, normal quotation marks prevent the shell from breaking the string into separate words, and escaped quotation marks are treated as literal characters. The backtick is the escape character.
These should work:
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="`"/your path/with spaces`""
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=`"$((your command)[0].name)`"
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="`"$((your command)[0].name) and some thing/ with spaces`""


tl;dr:

n. m. could be an AI's answer is the right solution for v7.3+ of PowerShell (Core) 7.

In (now obsolescent) lower versions as well as in Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1), you must additionally \-escape the embedded " characters.


For background information, read on.


Your fundamental problem was your use of a verbatim string (single-quoted, i.e. '...') when what you needed was a expandable (interpolating) string (double-quoted, i.e. "...")

Switching to "..." quoting then requires escaping the embedded " characters, typically as `", using `, the so-called backtick, PowerShell's escape character, though "" works too.

Instead of using embedded " to individually protect the spaces in your path, it is much simpler to enclose the entire RHS of = in embedded ":
# PowerShell 7.3+
... -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="`"-IC:/Program Files (x86)/.../$(...)/um`""




However, a long-standing bug in Windows PowerShell (and PowerShell 7 versions 7.2 and below) makes it necessary to additionally \-escape embedded " characters; combined with PowerShell's own escaping, this means: \`" is needed inside "..." in order to correctly pass an embedded, escaped " character through to an external target program such as cmake.exe.
  # Windows PowerShell (and PowerShell 7.2-)
  ... -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="\`"-IC:/Program Files (x86)/.../$(...)/um\`""


See this answer for background information.

Note that if you need to write cross-edition scripts, you can get v7.3+ to exhibit the old behavior by setting $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'



Note that cmake is unusual in that it requires escaped " characters to be embedded in its arguments, even though it should be capable of recognizing -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-IC:/Program Files (x86)/.../$(...)/um" as a single argument, which it receives with the unescaped " characters stripped (e.g., verbatim -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-IC:/Program Files (x86)/.../x/um)

Apparently, however, part of the value to the right of = - if it doesn't use embedded quoting - is then in effect split into tokens by whitespace and the resulting tokens are passed on to the C/C++ compiler behind the scenes as multiple arguments.



